# Is this a Valid Email "xyz@abc.com.com.com.com"?

Tags: html, email-validation

Is this a Valid Email "xyz@abc.com.com.com.com" ? I have seen Email IDs like "xyz@yahoo.co.in"

You may replace .COMs with some other string.

The point is **How many sub regional domains can an Email ID have ?**

I am planning to mark an Email field in my project as a bug. I normally mark them as bug if there are more than 3 parts separated by . symbol after the @ symbol.

Comment: There's no such thing as "sub regional domains". The domain name system doesn't care or categorise the kinds of "sub domains". `foo` is a domain name. `bar.foo` is a domain name with a sub domain. `baz.bar.foo` has *two* sub domains. `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.p.q.r.s.t.u.v.w.x.y.z` has 25 sub domains. If I'm the owner of `z`, I have the power to create all those sub domains if I so wish.

Comment: so in an email id, how many subdomains can we add ? how many are allowed to be called as a Valid email id ?

Comment: See the duplicate. The whole question is somewhat pointless though, since there's a large divide between the theoretical RFC which defines the desired behaviour, and the practical implementation of email servers, clients and website developers like you. In practice, any email address that is *deliverable* is valid. That means any address whose domain resolves and whose email server accepts the recipient name. That may or may not conform to the RFC specs. **The domain name can most certainly be longer than 3 parts!**